# Remote Desktop Connection: Don't connect to console

Tags: terminal-server, terminal

I've already seen the questions regarding connecting multiple different users from other machines into one server, but my question is a little different.

I want to create a remote desktop session from the console to the local machine (as a work around `not-so-`Fast User Switching), but using the standard MSTSC program always attempts to connect to the "console" session.

Is there a way to initiate a remote connection to localhost in such a way?

### In other words...

Normally, using remote desktop requires two machines, a server and a client that connects to the server. These two machines are usually separate from each other (i.e. you can't use the server as a client to itself).

I want to use the server as a client connecting to itself. At the moment this doesn't seem possible using the standard Remote Desktop Client, because it tries to connect to the Console session, and you can't have two simultaneous Console sessions active at the same time.

The goal here is to have the Remote Desktop Client connect to the local machine, but not try to connect to the Console session.

Comment: .....What.....?

Comment: So, say you want to use Remote Desktop from another PC. All other things set up correctly, you can't remote desktop into the same machine (as it connects to the console, which isn't allowed).

Comment: You want to connect via RDP to a computer from the same computer? That makes no sense. If you're talking about connecting to a desktop OS (Windows Vista, Windows 7, etc.) then yes you'll connect to the console. Desktop OS's don't support multiple concurrent RDP sessions.

Comment: @joeqwerty Right. I guess I didn't mention I was using Server 2012. In any case, this doesn't work in Server 2012 (or 2008 R2 apparently) either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having server version isn't enough, to have concurrent rdp sessions, you need to add terminal services server role, which needs its own license. Your best bet to get a console, as in terminal window, is to have a free ssh server installed on the server, and then as many users as you wish can access the machine. Of course, it will not be graphical and it needs  another server application so that may not work perfect for you.

Comment: Right, I don't need a command window. I already have concurrent connections enabled, but they only work with clients off of the server (I can have up to ten connected if they're not the server). I want to be logged on locally to the server, initiate a remote desktop connection on said server as if it were from an external client.

Comment: What is the purpose then? Like what you cannot do on a regular session that can be done on a remote session. BTW, on Windows Server, you can connect to the same physical session that you had using a remote session and visa versa (assuming you are using the same user who opened the session) and even a single user can have multiple sessions.

Comment: Essentially, I'm testing user/group permissions with a dummy account. This amounts to me making a change to the group policy, invoking a "Switch User", logging in as the test user, testing, logging out, then logging back into the administrator session again. This is very time consuming, but if I had a remote desktop session, I wouldn't need to leave the admin session at all. I suppose I could just provision another machine and invest in a KVM switch, but why do things in hardware what you can do in software amiright? :P

Comment: Or, RDP to the desktop and from it, RDP with test user back. No KVM needed. As for the other PC (and to skip RDP back), you might want to do a VM either with Hyper-V, or you other VMM of choice. You can keep it in a private Virtual Network too.

Comment: I suppose that's going to be the easiest solution. Mind putting that in another answer?